# How to compress a time series where the only values are 1, 0, and -1

Tags: compression, bit

I am trying to efficiently store a huge number ( > 1 billion) time series.  Each value can only be 1, 0 or -1 and the value is recorded once a minute for 40,000 minutes.

I realize that each minute the value can be stored in 2 bits, but I think there is an easier way:  there are a limited number of permutations for any time period, so I could just assign a number to each permutation instead of recording all the bits.

For example, if I were to take a 16 minute period: to record those values would require (16 x 2 bits) = 32 bits = 4 bytes.  But presumably, I can cut that number in half (or more) if I simply assign a number to each of the 16 possible permutations.

My question: what is the formula for determining the number of permutations for 16 values?  I know how to calculate it if the values can be any number, but am stumped as to how to do it when there are just 3 values.

Comment: Is it for storage?

Comment: Yes, it is for storage

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a number to each of the 16 possible permutations"? What 16 permutations do you mean?

Comment: Each minute can have a value of 0, 1, or -1.  So for a 16 minute period, there are x number of permutations.  For example, if all 16 minutes had a value of 1, that would be 1 permutation.  If they all had a value of -1, that would be another permutation.

Comment: Assuming that the value each minute is independent of the value of other minutes, there are 3^16 = 4.3e7 possible sets of data. If you wanted, you could encode this to fit into 26 bits instead of 32, but this doesn't seem tremendously useful.

Comment: Oh, @VeeArr, I understand now that I know the formula.  I had assumed that the number of permutations would have been less than 65,000 and could be encoded in 2 bytes.  That formula is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I'm curious. "value is recorded once a minute for 40,000 minutes" -- that's 40 thousand samples, how do you get to a billion? Are there 25 thousand independent variables sampled? You're obviously not sampling for 2 millennia, or I'm not getting something here. Or are there 1 billion independent 40 thousand sample time series?

Comment: We get to a billion because we are doing thousands of transforms each minute for each time series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance you can zip the file and you will get a great compression level with only 3 symbols.

If you want to do hard work, you can do what basic zip algorithms do:

You have 3 values -1, 0, and 1.

Then you can define a transaltion tree like:

```
bit sequence - symbol  
0            - 0  
10           - 1  
110          - -1  
1110          - End of data
```

So if you read a zero you know it is a 0 symbol, and if you read a 1 you have to read the next bit to know if it is a 1 or if you have to read one more to know if it is a -1.

So if you have a series 1,1,0,-1,0 it would translate as:

```
101001100
```

If this is all the data you see you have 9 bits, so you would need to complete with something to get to 16.

Then just put an end of data marker and after that anytihg.

```
10100110 01110000
```

To do this you need to work with bit operators.

If you know that any of these symbols has a rate of occurance greater that the rest, use that symbol with less amount of bits (for example the 0 should represent the most used symbol).

Comment: That code is no better than 00, 01, 10, 11 for the same symbols in the case where -1, 0, and 1 are equally likely. Actually that code in this answer would take two bits more, since the average for the samples is still two bits each, but the end of data code is two bits longer than it needs to be. That code is only potentially useful, though not optimal, if there is some significant difference in the probabilities. It is better to group symbols to get good performance from a prefix code.

Comment: @MarkAdler That depends on the distribution of the symbols. For example if 50% of the time the value is 0, you are using only 1 bit for 50% of the symbols instead of 2. I am not sayint this is better under every condition but it is better thatn using 2 bits for everything at least in some situations.

Comment: You apparently missed the phrase “equally likely”.

Answer (score 2):

If -1, 0, and 1 are all equally likely, then the formula for the number of bits required for *n* samples is *ceiling(n log<sub>2</sub>3)*. For one sample, you get two bits as you have noted, effectively wasting one of the states, a little more than 0.4 bits per sample wasted.

As it turns out, five samples fit really nicely into eight bits, where 3<sup>5</sup> = 243, with only about 0.015 bits per symbol wasted.

You can use the extra states as end-of-stream symbols. For example, you could use five of the remaining 13 states to signal end-of-stream, indicating that there are 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 samples remaining. Then if it's 1, 2, 3, or 4, there is one more byte with those samples. A little better would be to use three states for the 1 case, providing the sample in that byte. Then seven of the 13 states are used, requiring one byte to end the stream for the 0 and 1 cases, and two bytes to end the stream for the cases of 2, 3, or 4 remaining.

If -1, 0, and 1 have noticeably different probabilities, then you can use Huffman coding on the samples to represent the result in fewer bits than the "flat" case above. However there is only one Huffman code for one sample of three symbols, which would not give good performance in general. So you would again want to combine samples for better Huffman coding performance. (Or use arithmetic coding, but that is more involved than perhaps necessary in this case.) So you could again group five samples into one integer in the range 0..242, and Huffman code those, along with an end-of-stream symbol (call it 243) that occurs only once.